# How can I get the SQL Server instance names running based on a hostname (COMPUTERNAME)?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have only a hostname (what Microsoft calls a COMPUTERNAME). How can I get the names of SQL Server instances running on the host?

It appears from other answers that I could look through the services running on the host. However, it is a remote machine and I am not an Administrator for the host or any of the database instances. The organization has not begun to use PowerShell remoting.

Is there a better way? How can this be done?

Windows PowerShell

```
PS C:\> Get-Service -ComputerName Tyyyyyyy8B
Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'Tyyyyyyyy8B'. This operation might require other
privileges.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Service -ComputerName Tyyyyyyy8B
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.19041.2364
```

PowerShell Core

```
PS C:\> Get-Service -ComputerName Tyyyyyyy8B
Get-Service: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ComputerName'.
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.5
```

Comment: Why?  If you are performing a software inventory, there are tools for that.  Otherwise why not ask an admin or DBA for help?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I am a mere, lowly user. I thought I was asking an "admin or DBA for help" by asking in the SE Database Administrators group. There is significant organizational resistance to making work requests of another group. If Microsoft tools do not permit knowing instance names running on a host, please just say so.

Comment: That clears things up.  You would need significant priveliges on the target server to discover this.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Thank you. What is the minimum set of permissions I would need to ask for in order to discover SQL Server instances?

Answer (score 0):

> However, it is a remote machine

1
You don't need to remote to server to get list of services
just run
Get-Service -ComputerName yourserver
However you need some permissions on the server to get this list.
Problem - service names not always follow naming standard for all version

2
Ask registry on remote computer RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The `Get-Service` command has a `-ComputerName` parameter in Windows PowerShell. The parameter is not available in PowerShell Core. Using Windows Powershell 5.1, it appears that I do not have permission on the remote server. What is the minimum, specific permission(s) I should ask the AD/security people to grant in order do see the services on a machine? WRT 2) is that a VB function?

Comment: READ_CONTROL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-security-and-access-rights?redirectedfrom=MSDN#access_rights_for_the_service_control_manager

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/managing-services?view=powershell-5.1#getting-remote-services

Starting in PowerShell 6.0, the *-Service cmdlets don't have the ComputerName parameter. You can still get services on remote computers with PowerShell remoting. 


 
Second is not VB function - it's another way to query the server based on registry or in your case remote registry